# Program that copies its input to its output one character at a time

Tags: c, string, file, copy

I saw this copying method. In a loop, you read character one by one and you print them as well.
When i try to reproduce this i have several problems:

1. my loop never ends up - meaning there is no **EOF**;
2. my output is some weird char which repeat itself- whatever character/ character sequence I input;

I have tried with `int` as well as with `char` , but i red [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56728692/write-a-program-to-copy-input-to-output)  and i understood that it should be int because char does not have the `EOF` terminator.

Also i do not understand why use `int` when it should be `char`.

```
int x;

while(x = getchar() != EOF){
    putchar(x);
}

return 0;
```

I was expecting copying my input text to output, and then exit with code 0.
The actual output is: . (not visible here).

Comment: It's a matter of [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) as `x = getchar() != EOF` is actually equal to `x = (getchar() != EOF)`.

Comment: And because `char` could be signed or unsigned and `EOF` is an `int`, [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) and similar function returns an `int` otherwise the comparison to `EOF` could fail (an unsigned `char` would not be equal to `EOF`).

Comment: Even if i **correct my mistake** ***while((x = getchar()) != EOF)***, my while never ends.

Comment: Do you press the "end of file" sequence when inputting data? On Linux and macOS it's `Ctrl-D`, on Windows it's `Ctrl-Z` on an empty line.

Comment: When i press **enter** isn't equivalent to EOF?

Comment: @DragosMakovei Of course not. Don't you want to be able to have line breaks in files? ;)

Comment: @DragosMakovei EOF = END OF FILE. Are you thinking of EOF means END OF LINE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(x = getchar() != EOF)
```

should be

```
while((x = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Your code is equivalent to

```
while(x = (getchar() != EOF))
```

> Also i do not understand why use int when it should be char.

Because EOF cannot be represented by a `char`. All values that can be represented by a `char` can also be represented by an `int`, but not the other way around. But unless `getchar()` returns EOF, it will return a value that can be represented by a char. So this code is perfectly ok:

```
while((x = getchar()) != EOF) {
    char c = x; // Will always work if you have checked for EOF
```

### Important!

Note that this:

```
char x;
while((x = getchar()) != EOF)
```

will "work". It will end the loop on EOF. But there will also be another value that will be wrongfully interpreted as EOF. That can be demonstrated with this snippet:

```
char c = EOF;
if((char)255 == c)
       printf("Ooops!\n");
```

Comment: _But there will also be another value that will be wrongfully interpreted as EOF. That can be demonstrated with this snippet_ Why is this ?

Answer (score 0):

> my loop never ends up - meaning there is no EOF

### It is needed to input the "end of file" sequence when inputting data:

-On *Linux* and *macOS* it's **Ctrl-D**;

-On *Windows* it's **Ctrl-Z**;

E.g. inputting `^ZinputSequence` will result in no output followed by the termination of the program

> my output is some weird char which repeat itself- whatever character/ character sequence I input;

### It's a matter of operator precedence (a pair of brackets is missing)

```
while(x = getchar() != EOF)
```

should be

```
while((x = getchar()) != EOF)
```

In my case this was happening:

```
while(x = (getchar() != EOF))
```

Meaning that ***x*** was equal to ***true***, respectively ***1***. So the ***putchar()*** was outputting the equivalent of 1 in ASCII table.(SOH - start of heading, represented in my console as a smiley-face).

> Also i do not understand why use ***int*** when it should be ***char***.

It is needed something different for *indicating the end*, and it could't be a ***char*** variable (which in fact is a number between 0-255 ), as each of those numbers is a well defined character.

- EOF is an integer defined in `<stdio.h>` but the numeric value does not matter so much, as long as it cannot be confused with any real character.

---

Thanks to @**klutt** and @**Some programmer dude** for them answers.